# How to align output in consistent format

Tags: python

As You can see the first 4 columns are align correctly,
but When I append LOCKED column in the end, its format is very strange.

Here my code

```
    show_camera_in_command = "\t".join(camera.split(",,,")[0:-1])
    if locked:
        p_yel(show_camera_in_command+"\t\tLOCKED")
    else:
        print(show_camera_in_command)
```

Output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact your column with a kind of identifier has a size variable. You need to first check the longest string and then, according to its size, add relevant tabs needed.

You can calculate the number of tabs (where a tab is equal to 8 spaces) to insert between the identifier and LOCKED with a simple formula:

```
# Just make a simple relevant sample with different size
>>> lst = ["a", "aaaa", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"]
>>> for a in lst:
...     print "%s\tLOCKED" % a
...
a       LOCKED
aaaa    LOCKED
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa LOCKED  # Here we can see the problem

>>> max_size = len(lst[-1])
>>> for a in lst:
...     print "%s%sLOCKED" % (a, "\t" * ((max_size - len(a))/8 + 1))
...
a               LOCKED
aaaa            LOCKED
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa LOCKED
```

For simplicity, you can separate the print statement in two instructions:

```
nb_tabs = (max_size - len(a))/8 + 1
print "%s%sLOCKED" % (a, "\t" * nb_tabs)
```

You'll need of course to calculate the maximum size, which can be done by a simple iteration over data like `size = max([len(x) for x in lst])`.

Answer (score 0):

The tab character forces the output to the next 'tab stop'. Consider the tab character as being 8 spaces. Since data like SF8172 is 6 characters, the frist '\t' pushes the output to the next "8 space" position and the second another 8 spaces. Output like NDB301ND8301 is 12 spaces so you have already passed the position that the first tab set the previous output line. Thus you move one additional "tab stop" along. Similarly VASTVVK_Station1 is even longer and passes that tab'tab stop' so it is even farther on the output line.

The output is exactly as you have specified.  The other columns are all inside the same tab area so they do not show the variation.

You can either use format or calculate the number of tab characters required. such as

```
i = (64 - len(field))//8
```

now output with '\t'*i in the output specification.

Comment: what if i want to align the LOCKED information in the same position? how to? any tip

Comment: @poc Use format or calculate the number of tabs required based on the size of the output field and used '\t'*i which puts out the correct number of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Use python's format. You can see example [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples).